# Laravel. unlink ('file path'): Permission Denied

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in Laravel. I was trying to delete some files from public folder of my project. Defined 'delete' function as follow

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $files = File::find($id);
    $filedelete = $files['name'];
    Storage::delete('public/upload/',$filedelete);
    $files->delete();
    return back();
}
```

when I press delete input in my view

```
<a href="{{ action('FileController@delete',$link['id']) }}" class="btn btn warning">
  <button id="elimina" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Elimina</button>
</a>
```

with this route in web.php

```
Route::get('/showFile/{id}/delete',['as'=>'delete', 'uses'=>'FileController@delete']);
```

it gives me this error message

```
unlink(C:\wamp64\www\laravel\[nameproject]\storage\app\public/upload): Permission denied
```

(Trying) to be as clear as possible, I upload a file in a database and in this folder. $id is the primary key of the table where there is the reference of this file. I think my problem is with $files['name'] because if I write the exact name of the file it works. But I need to make this delete dynamic, for sure. I hope to be clear, I'm sorry if not.

Thanks a lot in advance. All the best.

PS With this line in function delete, it works

```
Storage::delete('public/upload/[filename]');
```

Edit

```
$files = File::find($id);
$filedelete = $files['name'];
return "".$filedelete;
```

it returns me the correct name of the file. So, my problem is just how to delete it from that folder?

Comment: Is your C drive protected by UAC or it is admin access only?

Comment: No protection, admin access only. I can add and edit files, just not delete, if I don't insert the name of file manually

Comment: If you think the issue is with the name, output the name prior to delete and see if it as you expect. Also, when you write a file to disk it is not necessarily owned by the same user as is running the php delete function.

Comment: You're right but in this case I'm sure that creator is the same user cause there's just one, it's a particular webapp. I've tried your advice returning $filedelete and it works, the name is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you stored the reference to the file in the db so this should work:

```
$files = File::find($id);
Storage::delete('public/upload/'.$files->filePathColumnName);
```

Changed the , to a . in your delete.
Would probably go with:

```
public_path().'/uploads/'.$files->filePathColumnName
```

depending on how much of the path you put in the db

Comment: Nothing man, I've written with your code but it deletes the voice from db but not from storage folder

Comment: Try dd('the/path/to/the/file) so you are sure the file exists and the other thought is put a backslash in front of \Storage::delete

Comment: Finally it works! Thank you so much BobB, I wish you all the best :) Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when I opened the a file:

```
$handle = @fopen($filepath, "r");
```

But didn't close it after reading.

To fix this I added a file close command after reading the content of the file

```
fclose($handle);
```